# I'm having an error with downloading discord.py on my macOS

Tags: python, macos, terminal

I keep getting an error message when trying to install discord.py with pip. My Python is at 3.6.5 but terminal says 2.7.16. When trying to install discord.py, this is the code that comes up. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8LeB.png)

Answer (score 0):

pip is defaulted to 2.7 on your system.
you have 2 easy options:

1. use `pip3`
2. create virtualenv of 3.6, activate and run pip on it.